# How can I set the correct bounds to a view when the device rotates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I have a programmatically created UIScrollView, and I am creating it as the size of the UIView behind it. In `viewDidAppear` I basically have:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView= [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:mainView.bounds];
//mainView being the UIView behind
```

When the device rotates, naturally the UIView in the background changes bounds to wider and shorter(though x,y ≠ y,x).

In my `-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` I put `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(mainView.bounds));, and the mainView's bounds has switched, but if I do this:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    scrollView.bounds = mainView.bounds;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(scrollView.bounds));
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(mainView.bounds));
}
```

It still shows up wrong.. 
The NSLog logs out the same bounds for both views, but on screen the mainView is correct, and the scrollView seems flipped or something, as if (0,0) in origin is outside the mainView, and the sizes are flipped wrong..
Do I have to redraw something, or am I calling all of this in the wrong place? Or isn't `.bounds` the right variable to use?

**EDIT**

I realize that updating the frame is different than re-initiating it with `initWithFrame:`, but I want the current content to stay the same, in the same way..

Comment: Is this your actual code or could there be a copy/paste error? Because it should be `NSLog(@"%@", ...)`, not `NSLog("%@", ...)`.

Comment: Yes, I typed this by hand, so it has nothing to do with that, I'll get that fixed, thanks;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the scrollview's frame not it's bounds

```
scrollView.frame = mainView.bounds;
```

Or better yet if you set up the correct autoresizing masks/constraints it will resize automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed some of it, but not everything.. I have made the UIView in the background gray, so that I can see when it pops out in the background, and using your code makes it never show gray, thats good. BUT, when I'm zooming in the scrollView, there seems to be a cutoff. But while writing this I realize that may be the content of the scrollView not updating the bounds..? Anyway, as to autorezise/constraints, can I do that to a programmatically created ScrollView?